# Quotient of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question about convergent sequences which I have no idea how to go about.

It seems intuitive to me that if we have two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that they both have a limit ($+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are acceptable), then their quotient also has a limit.

However, I have no idea whether this is correct and I've searched but found nothing.

Is it possible that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ might not have a limit such as the case with $(-1)^n$

I really appreciate if someone can provide either a counterexample if it's wrong or a proof if it's correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's False. Let $a_n=\frac{|\sin n|}{n},\ b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, both $ a_n$ and $ b_n$ converge to $0$ but $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$=$|\sin n|$.

Comment: Actually, that has a limit. I said $+\infty$ is acceptable.

Comment: In your example, $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to+\infty$ which means that a limit exists. I wanted to know if there's a case in which the limit doesn't even exist.

Comment: @HasanSaad Oh ,sorry to misunderstand your meaning,let $a_n=\frac{\sin n}{n} ,b_n=\frac1n$...

Comment: Just edit it to $|\sin n|$ and it'll be a perfect answer. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not true, for example take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$. Both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converge to $0$ but $a_n/b_n = (-1)^n$. Hence the quotient doesn't converge at all.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see that for some reason. Does it hold for positive sequences of is it the same?